# How to disable a pigpio gpioSetISRFunc()

Tags: pigpio

Im using pigpio to listen to an external interrupt. I have set it this way

```
gpioSetISRFunc(13,FALLING_EDGE,10,aFunction);
```

Now i would like to stop listening for the interrupt. How do i disable that function i just have set? The [documentation](https://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/cif.html#gpioSetISRFunc) does not really say how to disable it without terminating the program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The ISR may be cancelled by passing a NULL f, in which case the GPIO is unexported.

E.g.

```
gpioSetISRFunc(13,FALLING_EDGE,10, NULL);
```

or perhaps clearer

```
gpioSetISRFunc(13, 0, 0, NULL);
```

Comment: Thank you, Im sorry i was quick to ask without reading the texts. What is the difference between the 2? the first one feels like it does not stop listening but instead just removes the associated function. Is the second one better?

Comment: They should both have the same effect of cancelling the ISR.  I think the second example makes the intention clearer to a reader.

Comment: Oh i see , Thank you very much. Slight off topic though is it possible to pass a parameter to the function parameter. Soemthing along the lines of `gpioSetISRFunc(13,FALLING_EDGE,10,aFunction(true));`

Comment: You should probably be using gpioSetISRFuncEx().